# Position dialog form on Main form

Tags: c#

I'm new user and work with Winform. I have a problem to position the child form dialog on main form application. I want move it to bottom right corner of main form window but my code don't work. I don't understand. Please help me .

```
        basketForm = new Basket();
        basketForm.Owner = this;
        basketForm.Show();
        Point pt = new Point(0, 0);
        pt.X = this.Right - basketForm.Width;
        pt.Y = this.Bottom - basketForm.Height;
        pt = this.PointToScreen(pt);
        basketForm.Location = pt;
```

Comment: Don't call PointToScreen, it is already in screen coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You need set the point configuration before showing the window.